# Decrementing an ArrayList

Tags: java

I wanted to know how I can decrement a specific number in a nested arrayList without assigning it a variable however.

Here is my code, however it is giving me an error, whenever I try to decrement the value at a specific position.

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>(); 
      ArrayList<Integer> al1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<Integer> al2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      al1.add(20);
      al1.add(20);
      al1.add(20);
      al1.add(20);
      al1.add(20);
      al2.add(20);
      al2.add(20);
      al2.add(20);
      al2.add(20);
      al2.add(20);
      a.add(al1);
      a.add(al2);


      a.get(0).get(0) -= 1;
```

Comment: That isn't assignable; you need to get the value and set it back.

Comment: `a.get(0).set(0, a.get(0).get(0) - 1);`

Comment: (Tangentially related, but instead of "it's giving me an error", it's better to provide the error.)